# How can I store a text file from a Python C extension

Tags: python, c, installation

If I have a C extension which loads a text file during runtime, say for an OpenCL kernel, how can I have the C extension read the file during runtime without having to pass it in as a variable? Currently, I have a setup script for the following directory layout,

```
|-myproj/
  |-kernels/
    |-kernel1.cl
  |-src/
    |-srcFile1.c
    ...
  |-headers/
    |-header1.c
    ...
  |-setup.py
```

and the setup file states

```
my_extension = Extension("myproj",
    include_dirs = ["headers"],
    libraries = ["OpenCL"],
    sources = ["src/srcFile1.c", ...])

setup(name = "myproj",
      version = "0.0.1",
      ext_modules = [my_extension],
      data_files = [('kernels', ['kernels/kernel1.cl', ...])])
```

Now, in my C source, which loads the kernel source, I have it print the current working directory. It is not the directory of the binary, but the directory of the directory which python is running in. Is there a way to have the c program read the kernel source from inside the installation directory?

Answer (score 0):

Just like Python modules do, Python C Extensions get a `__file__` attribute, but only *after* their module initialization function returns (determined by testing in Python 2.7.3 on Debian Wheezy).  In a fully initialized C extension, you can simply use `PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "__file__")` to retrieve this path and then act on it. (you may want to save the pointer returned from `Py_InitModule()` to module-level global so you have it when you need it)

However, you may find it more maintainable to have at least one pure Python module in your package.  It can use its own `__file__` even before it's done loading, and it can more conveniently use `os.path` operations to form the name of the name of the file you want to operate on.  Finally, it is advantageous because you can potentially allow a client of your library to choose a different OpenCL kernel if it is appropriate.